# About generalized Springer theory for spin groups

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I am interested in the detailed computation of the generalized Springer theory for spin groups (type B or D). The last sentense in Section 14 of Lusztig's *Intersection cohomology complex on a reductive group* he wrote *"It is likely that, if $(C,\mathcal{E})\in\mathcal{N}_{\chi}^{(0)}$ and $g\in C$, then the sizes of the Jordan cells $\beta(g)\in SO(V)$ give the partition $N=1+5+9+13+...$ or $N=3+7+11+15+...$."*

In other words, the sizes of Jordan blocks of the unipotent orbits that support those new cuspidal local systems that live in $Spin_N$ but not $SO_N$ were predicted as above. Has this computation been completed somewhere? And if so what are the local systems attached to these orbits? Thanks!

Comment: a more precise reference might help - there are many monumental papers by Lusztig...

Comment: As Dima suggests, a citation would be helpful.   Though Lusztig wrote many follow-up papers involving character sheaves, his formulation of the "generalized Springer correspondence" was probably first given in :http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=732546

Comment: Exactly the first paper. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: P.S. Your question is reasonable, but if you edit it further please omit the first word, write "detailed" in place of "detail", change "lives" to "live", and change "system" to "systems".    (And it wouldn't hurt to explain Lusztig's notational conventions briefly.)

Comment: Thanks! I rephrase the second paragraph a bit, which should now explain (what we need for) Lusztig's notation.

Comment: In Lusztig's article, before Proposition 14.4. he explains that these local systems correspond to spinorial representations referring to Bourbaki. So, is not that enough ?

Comment: My apology if I am misunderstanding badly - I thought the paragraph mostly explains what are the possible local systems (those don't live in $SO_N$, but not necessarily cuspidal) for later counting purpose?

Comment: Yes that's right, but he says that for all unipotent classes there is at most one in \mathcal{M}_{\chi}. So, the one in the class parametrized by (3,7,...) or (1,5,...) is cuspidal. Isn't it ?

Comment: We know others are not cuspidal? Or maybe this follows from something that I just don't know. I'll be grateful to learn!

Comment: Which others ? There is at most one local system on a unipotent class for which the center acts by \chi.